# How to get list of my own application list from google play

Tags: android, google-play

I have published few applications on Google play and they are live as well. Does Google play exposes any rest API ? So that I can list out all my applications on Google play and show it to the user in the current application. 
Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

As such there is no API exist by which you get fetch apps list. Here is a documentation on [Linking to Your Products](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html), from this page you can find out [Linking to your product list](https://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/promote/linking.html#OpeningPublisher).

Answer (score 0):

Answer is below,would help some one :)

```
 private void showMyApps(){
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/search?q=pub:publisher name"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```